# IIS asks for login credentials only on a specific folder

Tags: iis-7, permissions, http-status-code-401

i have on IIS 7 a site which has several sub folders. the site was built using .net 2 and is running in a pool in integrated mode.

the whole site works perfectly except for all aspx files under a folder called "Reports". 
when the user is trying to access any aspx page under that folder (i.e. http://domain/Reports/page1.aspx) he gets a 401 response and the browser prompts for a user and password.

this happens when accessing the site remotely and locally. when trying to look on the IIS log files the request is not listed as if it is blocked by something.

i have done the following tests to try and resolve this:

2. i have renamed the folder to R1 and then i could access any page on it
3. i have taken another working folder and renamed it to Reports and was then unable to access any of the files within it
4. i have reset the permissions over and over without success
5. i thought about Request filtering but i see no filter for a URL containing the word "Reports". also we have not set any filter so i should be working on the default IIS settings
6. i have created a simple html file and was unable to access it too. again the 401 error

seems like IIS just does not like a folder called "Reports". any ideas on what i am missing here?

Comment: Do you have any `<location>` [entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(VS.80).aspx) in your web.config mentioning Reports?

Comment: no i don't. i also don't have any for other folders that do work. i do have a few location settings in the web.config but they relate to other folders. and work as expected

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is SQL Server installed on the server, specifically SQL Server Reporting Services? Apparently it [can cause problems](http://forums.iis.net/t/1157304.aspx) with a Reports folder

*Completely separate idea, so separate answer*

Comment: yes it is. SQL reporting was installed and took the /Reports folder. took me 2 hours of fighting this until i gave up and 5 seconds once you put me in the correct direction! thank you very much!

Comment: I want to have your babies. I lost a day to this. An entire day. If not more.

Comment: Seriously, I can't believe this. I spent an entire working day trying to solve this. I chopped an entire web application back to the barebones and slowly re-assembled it. And just couldn't put my finger on it. Never in a thousand years would I have figured this out if I hadn't stumbled upon this thread which inexplicably didn't turn up in the previous day's worth of stackoverflow searches

Comment: Thank god I found this early or I would have lost days too. So if you don't want this behaviour from SQL Server and do want a "reports" folder in your site, you can change the folder name that SQL reporting reserves by running "Reporting Services Configuration Manager". Go to "Report Manager URL" and change the "Virtual Directory" setting to something less likely to cause conflicts.