# Windows Security dialog appears when a user tries to access certain pages on my site

Tags: asp.net, security

I have published an `ASP.NET` web site which targets `ASP.NET 3.5` to a W`indows Server 2008` machine which uses `IIS 7` to serve the web pages. Some of the pages on the site work just fine. But any attempt to access the `.aspx` pages within a certain folder `("Reports")` will cause the Windows Security login dialog to display, as if the user is trying to log onto the server.

The bizarre thing is this...if I simply rename the folder to `"Reports_Test"` and try to access the very same `.aspx` files, no Windows Security dialog appears, and the pages seem to work just fine. It is as if the name `"Reports"` has some special meaning to something in the configuration of the site. I have searched through the `web.config` file for any mention of the the work `"Reports"` and there are none.

The actual folder, whether named `"Reports"` or `"Reports_Test"` has all the same security settings and permissions as the other folders, which do not display the security dialog.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can debug this bizarre problem?

Comment: Is it possible that you're navigating to the pages incorrectly in your code?

Comment: No...that was my first thought but, the urls are correct. Even if I manually type in the URL, it will not work. If I change the name of the folder to anything other than "Reports" and then type the new URL in, it works. One other thing...while the folder is renamed to something else, if I try to go to www.mysite/Reports/Reports.aspx, I don't get the "Resource not found" error I expect (since there is no folder named "Reports"). I STILL get the Windows Security login. Its crazy. (Thanks for your response)

Comment: Hmm... that is really strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check on some of your report pages, and make sure that your reports don't have any invalid or empty image URLs. Apparently, this can cause the kind of problems that you're experiencing, because the server will attempt to search root directory.

I would suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to monitor what's going on when you try to access these pages.

**EDIT**

This issue is related to SQL Server Reporting Services. These links provide the answer:

- [IIS asks for login credentials only on a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805628/iis-asks-for-login-credentials-only-on-a-specific-folder)
- http://forums.iis.net/t/1157304.aspx

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer. But, it is a partial answer. I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805628/iis-asks-for-login-credentials-only-on-a-specific-folder and here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1157304.aspx. I believe the image URL problem you describe may have caused this problem because it forced IIS to search for images starting in the root. My "Reports" folder is not in the root folder but the image search probably caused IIS to search the Reports folder created/reserved by Reporting Services, as the links describe. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: So it was SQL Server Reporting Services? That makes sense. Glad you got it working. I'll incorporate these links into my answer for anybody who comes across this issue in the future.